Using 32byte keys establish platform scp03 secure channel
I want establish a scp03 secure channel.
My static keys are of length 32bytes or 256bits
Using 32 byte keys I want to generate session keys according to scp03 protocol,
when I tried implementing after generating session keys when I use the generate mac key to verify card cryptogram it is failing.
Following are steps that I have implemented:

Initialize update
Generate session keys. According to diversification scheme
input for session-enc - 11(0's)+derivation constant(0x04-enc,0x06-mac,0x07-rmac)+00(separation indicator)+0x0100(L value bcz 32 byte key length)+0x02+hostchallange(8 bytes)+card challenge(8 bytes) -- total 32 bytes

This is how I generate enc, mac, r-mac keys

Verify card cryptogram - I use 16byte generated mac key and applied derivation scheme. When I am verifying the card cryptogram which is 8 bytes the comparison is failing.

Can I know the proper values to generate session keys and verify card cryptogram

Please take some time to read the the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples. As your question stands now there is insufficient information to be able to help you.

globalplatform for c on GitHub can do this. There might be also a test case in a file scp03Test.c
